# Wrapped function is only called from linked library when linking as -static

Tags: c++, gcc, static, linker, wrapper

*Edit*: Made title a bit clearer.

I am trying to wrap glibc's `__assert_fail` and `__assert_perror_fail` functions with my own that log the messages using `syslog`.

I have verified that if I fail an assert my functions get called. The problem lies in libzmq's assertions. libzmq's assertions only invoke my wrapper functions when I build with `-static`.

**NOTES**

- I patched libzmq to call `__assert_*` instead of `fprintf(stderr, ...)`, and I have verified that it correctly calls `__assert_*`.
- I also patched libzmq to randomly have assertion failures from within the zmq_assert macros so that I can easily reproduce. If the patch is wanted, I will put it up.

Here is some test code

```c++
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <zmq.h>

extern "C" void
__wrap___assert_perror_fail(int __errnum, const char *__file,
                            unsigned int __line, const char *__function)
{
        fprintf(stderr, "TESTING123:: %s:%u %s: Unexpected error: %s.\n",
                __file, __line, __function, strerror(__errnum));
        abort();
}

extern "C" void
__wrap___assert_fail(const char *__assertion, const char *__file,
                     unsigned int __line, const char *__function)
{
        fprintf(stderr, "TESTING123:: %s:%u %s: Assertion '%s' failed.\n",
                __file, __line, __function, __assertion);
        abort();
}

int main()
{
#ifdef DO_ASSERT
        assert(1 == 0);
#endif
        void *ctx = zmq_init(0);
        void *req = zmq_socket(ctx, ZMQ_REQ);
        void *rep = zmq_socket(ctx, ZMQ_REQ);
        zmq_bind(rep, "inproc://inproc-1");
        zmq_connect(req, "inproc://inproc-1");
        unsigned long long c = 0;
        while (1) {
                zmq_msg_t msg;

                zmq_msg_init_size(&msg, 1024);
                zmq_send(req, &msg, 0);
                zmq_msg_close(&msg);

                zmq_msg_init(&msg);
                zmq_recv(rep, &msg, 0);
                zmq_send(rep, &msg, 0);
                zmq_msg_close(&msg);

                zmq_msg_init(&msg);
                zmq_recv(req, &msg, 0);
                zmq_msg_close(&msg);

                ++c;
                if (c % 1000000 == 0) {
                        fprintf(stderr, "processed %llu messages\n", c);
                }
        }
        return 0;
}
```

Which I build 4 ways with/without DO_ASSERT, dynamic/static

```sh
$ g++ -DDO_ASSERT -o t-me-dyn t.cc -Wl,-wrap,__assert_fail -Wl,-wrap,__asser_perror_fail -lzmq -lpthread -luuid -lrt 
$ g++ -static -DDO_ASSERT -o t-me-sta t.cc -Wl,-wrap,__assert_fail -Wl,-wrap,__asser_perror_fail -lzmq -lpthread -luuid -lrt 
$ g++ -o t-zmq-dyn t.cc -Wl,-wrap,__assert_fail -Wl,-wrap,__asser_perror_fail -lzmq -lpthread -luuid -lrt 
$ g++ -static -o t-zmq-sta t.cc -Wl,-wrap,__assert_fail -Wl,-wrap,__asser_perror_fail -lzmq -lpthread -luuid -lrt 
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.7.1/../../../../lib/libzmq.a(libzmq_la-ip.o): In function 'zmq::resolve_ip_interface(sockaddr_storage*, unsigned int*, char const*)':
(.text+0x49b): warning: Using 'getaddrinfo' in statically linked applications requires at runtime the shared libraries from the glibc version used for linking
```

And I get the following when running them

```sh
$ for bin in t-{me,zmq}-{dyn,sta}; do echo ==== $bin ====; ./$bin; done
==== t-me-dyn ====
TESTING123:: t.cc:29 int main(): Assertion '1 == 0' failed.
Aborted
==== t-me-sta ====
TESTING123:: t.cc:29 int main(): Assertion '1 == 0' failed.
Aborted
==== t-zmq-dyn ====
t-zmq-dyn: lb.cpp:142: int zmq::lb_t::send(zmq_msg_t*, int): Assertion 'rc == 0' failed.
Aborted
==== t-zmq-sta ====
TESTING123:: lb.cpp:142 int zmq::lb_t::send(zmq_msg_t*, int): Assertion 'rc == 0' failed.
Aborted
```

So what am I doing wrong? According to `man ld`

> If you link other code with this file using --wrap malloc, then all calls to "malloc" will call the function "__wrap_malloc" instead.

which is not what I am seeing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your mental model of how `--wrap` linker option works is likely all wrong.

It's quite simple really: when you are linking a particular ELF executable or shared library with `--wrap foo`, *all* the linker does is:

- if it sees a reference to `foo`, it replaces it with a reference to `__wrap_foo`,
- if it sees a reference to `__real_foo`, it replaces with a reference to `foo`.

I repeat, that is *all* it does. In particular, since you have not relinked `libzmq.so` with `--wrap`, `libzmq.so` continues to call `__assert_fail` (i.e. no renaming whatsoever is happening inside `libzmq.so`).

In order to interpose `libc` function, forget the `--wrap`.

Instead, simply *define* a new `__assert_fail` in your main executable. When you do that, your definition will get called regardless of whether the call comes from the main executable, or from `libzmq.so` (or from anywhere else).

If you don't want to call the version of `__assert_fail` from libc, you are done. If you do, you'll have to look it up dynamically (via `dlsym`).

Comment: I'm thinking that my idea of `--wrap` was wrong just like you say. I came to find `--wrap` after trying to define my own `__assert_fail`, but that didn't work. I will try it again to verify. I finally got it to work with `__attribute__((alias("my_assert_fail"))`

Comment: So I went back and tested both the example code posted here, and my application and they both work when I define `__assert_fail` and `__assert_perror_fail`! I wonder why I think it didn't work... Anyways @Employed thanks for the answer.