# unresolved symbol __real_malloc while dynamically loading a library which is compiled with --wrap=malloc

Tags: c++, linux, linker, dynamic-library, dynamic-loading

As mentioned in other SO answers I am using the wrapping mechanism of GNU ld to intercept calls to `malloc` on Linux (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3662856/how-to-reimplement-or-wrap-a-syscall-function-in-linux) for an example).
The used linker flag is `-Wl,--wrap=malloc` and the respective `void __wrap_malloc(size_t)` is also defined.
This works fine in a test application where all compilation unit are linked into the same binary.

Now, I need to modify a dynamically linked library which is loaded into a main program via `dlopen()`.
Linking the library succeeds, but loading it into the main program fails with `undefined symbol: __real_malloc`.

Running `nm` on the library shows that `__wrap_malloc` is defined but `__real_malloc` is not.
But, according to `man ld` and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12766024) SO answer, `malloc` should get replaced with `__wrap_malloc` and `__real_malloc` should point to `malloc` when using this technique.

In the test application, I see that `__real_malloc` is undefined in the compiled object files but is resolved after getting linked into the executable.

So, why is the symbol resolved in the test application but not in the dynamic library?
In both cases a final link step is performed which should resolve this symbol.
Or is it required to add another library during the link step of the dynamic library in order to get `__real_malloc` resolved?

Just in case, it is not possible to modify the target application which loads the dynamic library via `dlopen`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should work and only requires slight changes to the code in the question you linked.

testapp.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>

typedef void f_t(void);

int main()
{
    void* h = dlopen("./malloc_wrapper.so", RTLD_NOW);
    if (h == NULL)
    {
        puts(dlerror());
        exit(1);
    }

    f_t* f = (f_t*)dlsym(h, "test");

    if (f == NULL)
    {
        puts(dlerror());
        exit(1);
    }

    (*f)();

    return 0;
}
```

malloc_wrapper.c

```
#include <stdlib.h> /* added */
#include <stdio.h>
void *__real_malloc (size_t);

/* This function wraps the real malloc */
void *__wrap_malloc(size_t size)
{
    void *lptr = __real_malloc(size);
    printf("Malloc: %lu bytes @%p\n", size, lptr);
    return lptr;
}

void test(void) /* added */
{
    free(malloc(1024));
}
```

Compile and run.

```
gcc -Wl,-wrap,malloc -shared -fpic malloc_wrapper.c -o malloc_wrapper.so
gcc testapp.c -o testapp -ldl
./testapp
Malloc: 1024 bytes @0x1d44680
```

Compiling malloc_wrapper.so like this reproduces the error you describe:

```
gcc -shared -fpic malloc_wrapper.c -o malloc_wrapper.so
./testapp
./malloc_wrapper.so: undefined symbol: __real_malloc
```

Perhaps you were using wrap when compiling and linking the executable instead of the shared object?

Comment: Thanks for the example and sorry for getting back so late. After adding `extern "C"` declarations to the functions, changing includes to the `c++` equivalent, and compiling the files with `g++` it works for this example. Unfortunately, the project I am working with is much more complex. So it seems to be a problem in its build process. Maybe I'll update the question if I have more details on the issue.